# How to disable tap-to-click on keyboard with integrated touchpad & generic XP driver

Tags: windows-xp, touchpad, mouse-click

I have a KeySonic ACK-540RF+ keyboard with an **integrated touchpad**, running under **XP with all updates**. There is no special driver for this keyboard.

I would like to **disable tap-to-click**, but from what I can see from googling, the only way to do it is through device-specific drivers in the Mouse control panel.

My **generic XP mouse driver has no options for tap-to-click**. I tried to install a Synaptics driver, but it had no effect (the installation seemed to go fine, but there were no new options in the Mouse control panel).

Is there an **XP driver** that will work with a **generic touchpad**? Is there a **registry setting** for tap-to-click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to disable it because you accidentally hit the touchpad whilst you are typing and that no-one else can suggest a better solution, then you may wish to look at [TouchFreeze](http://code.google.com/p/touchfreeze/).

Comment: I do want to disable it because I accidentally touch it, but it's not only when I'm typing -- it's all the time. Still, I'll give TouchFreeze a go -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After waiting a long time for an answer and looking everywhere on the internet, I conclude that this question is unanswerable -- **there is no way to disable tap-to-click on a generic touchpad keyboard in Windows XP**.